# Escaping URL &'s when launching browser from Ruby script

Tags: ruby

Using ruby 1.9.2 I am writing a windows script that intends to launch a browser on a URL that contains a number of parameters. I have tried the various ways of launching a browser process:
  'start #{url}`
  system( "start #{url}" )
  ...

My URL contains a number of parameters and therefore contains &'s. The problem is that the &'s seem to be interpreted by the shell and I have not figured out how to escape them such that they are correctly passed to the browser.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`system` with several arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441):

> Executes *command* in a subshell. *command* is one of following forms.
>   [...]
>   `cmdname, arg1, ...`: command name and one or more arguments (no shell)

That would skip the shell completely and bypass the whole escaping issue. Try this:

```
system('start', url)
```

I'm not sure how `start` works with Windows but that should work if it is a separate executable.

Answer (score 0):

[Launchy](http://rubygems.org/gems/launchy) is also a fantastic gem that allows you to do this in a cross-platform way (in case you want to go beyond Windows).

Example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'launchy'
Launchy.open('http://www.google.com/search?&q=ruby')
```